# Play Multiple audio files through ExoPlayer or some other option?

Tags: android, media-player, soundpool, exoplayer2.x

My problem: I want to load 70 sounds in my app and then want to play multiple sound(maximum 8 sound at a time). Example app is below:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.relaxio.sleepo

I try SoundPool system in my app and it give me a problem in loading. SoundPool take about more then 60 seconds for loading 70 files. So this option is not good for my app. 
Then i try MediaPlayer. MediaPlayer is ok with loading but give another problem. When i set looping in mediaplayer then it give a gap between restarting. 
Then i found a github project that play multiple sound at a time and also the loading is fast but still i have problem with this project. It can't load more then 30 sounds properly. In this project they use ExoPlayer(link is below).
https://github.com/zoenb/Soft-Sound

Please help me what can i do so that the loading of sound and loop gap problem to be solved.

Comment: Are your sounds embedded within your application or do you have to download them first? How long are your sounds? 
I'm actually using several Exoplayer-instances within a Service in my app, and I can even play more than eight sounds at a time. (no looping, but restart is possible). check here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.jahpress.android

Comment: no issue with 8 sounds a time. issue of exoplayer occur when instances is more then 35. i have used it for 70 sounds. so it work upto 35 but after it it con't play some sounds

Comment: if you only want to play maximum 8 sounds at a time, i would suggest that you should have 8 instances of exoplayer and switch the sounds instead of keeping an instance for every sound. if i understood correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, you have to create multiple(8) instances of exoplayer, you can't do it with one instance

here is my code,

```
    private void initPlayer() {
      if (player == null) {
        trackSelectorParameters = new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder().build();
        TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory();
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelectorParameters);

        RenderersFactory renderersFactory = ((MyAppApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).buildRenderersFactory();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, renderersFactory, trackSelector);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        //to print log of ExoPlayer
        //player.addAnalyticsListener(new EventLogger(trackSelector));

        progressiveMediaSourceFactory = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);

      }
    }
```

use above code to initialize exoplayer and call this method to add all the 8 `URI`s to play at the same time

```
 public void startPlaying(Uri uri) {
        if (player == null) initPlayer();
        MediaSource mediaSource = progressiveMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
  }
```

here is the Github link - https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

use `exoplayer-core` library

for that, I would like to suggest you make a separate class to ExoPlayer to initialize, start, stop and all like...

```
public class MyAppExoPlayer {

private final Context context;


private DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory;
private SimpleExoPlayer player;
private DefaultTrackSelector trackSelector;
private DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters trackSelectorParameters;


private ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory progressiveMediaSourceFactory;


private ConcatenatingMediaSource concatenatingMediaSource;
private int currentMediaPlayerIndex = 0;

public MyAppExoPlayer(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    dataSourceFactory = ((MyAppApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).buildDataSourceFactory();

    initPlayer();
}

private void initPlayer() {
    if (player == null) {
        trackSelectorParameters = new DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder().build();
        TrackSelection.Factory trackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory();
        trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(trackSelectionFactory);
        trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelectorParameters);

        RenderersFactory renderersFactory = ((MyAppApplication) context.getApplicationContext()).buildRenderersFactory();

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, renderersFactory, trackSelector);

        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);

        //to print log of ExoPlayer
        //player.addAnalyticsListener(new EventLogger(trackSelector));

        progressiveMediaSourceFactory = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory);

    }

    concatenatingMediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource();
}

public void startPlaying(Uri uri) {
    if (player == null) initPlayer();
    MediaSource mediaSource = progressiveMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(uri);
    player.prepare(mediaSource, true, false);
}

public void addToQ(Uri uri) {
    if (player == null) return;
    MediaSource mediaSource = progressiveMediaSourceFactory.createMediaSource(uri);
    concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(mediaSource);
}

public void stopPlaying() {
    if (player != null) {
        player.stop(true);
        concatenatingMediaSource.clear();
    }
}

public long getCurrentPosition() {
    if (player != null)
        return player.getCurrentPosition();
    return 0;
}

public void releasePlayer() {
    if (player != null) {

        if (trackSelector != null) {
            trackSelectorParameters = trackSelector.getParameters();
        }

        player.release();
        player = null;
        trackSelector = null;
    }
}
}
```

Now create 8 instances if `MyAppExoPlayer` and call `startPlaying()`

Comment: ProgressiveMediaSource is showing error "unknown symbol". i use exoplayer version library "2.8.4"

Comment: same for "ExoPlayerStateListener"

Comment: use 2.10.0     `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.10.0'`

Comment: ProgressiveMediaSource issue is resolved but still ExoPlayerStateListener is remaining

Comment: ohh, it's not any listener inside lib, it is for my project only, you can remove this

Comment: sorry for irritating questions. what is "MyAppApplication" it also give same problem

Comment: which is application class, you can find all the things inside this link, please refer it https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/DemoApplication.java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196853/discussion-between-ibad-ur-rahman-and-priyankagb).

Comment: please help about volume setting.

Comment: you can use player.setVolume(volume);
use 0f for mute & 1f for full volume, the volume should be between 0 to 1